# Interfaces that inherit from a base interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, inheritance, interface

### Scenario:

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 and C#.  I have a lot of services that all have an Init() method.

So, I thought, inheritance is my new best friend. I have tried to inherit interfaces from other interfaces.

However, I am running into problems.

### What I have done:

As I understand it, one interface can inherit from another interface.  i.e, you can do this:

```
public interface ICaseService : IBaseService
{
    CaseViewModel ViewModel { get; }

    Case Case { get; set; }
}
```

Where:

```
public interface IBaseService
{
    void Init();
}
```

So when I derive CaseService from ICaseService I will have to implement the `Init()` method as well as the `Case` property and the `ViewModel` property.

### The Problem:

Lets say I now have a controller that has a reference to ICaseService:

```
private readonly ICaseService service;
```

In my actions, I reckon I should be able to do:

```
public virtual ActionResult MyAction()
{
    service.Init();
}
```

But I get an error message stating that `ICaseService` 'does not contain a definition for' `Init()`.

### Questions:

1. Why?
2. Do I have to forget about inheriting interfaces from interfaces and just type out in each interface definition the `Init()` method?

### Note:

The above is a simplified scenario.  My "base" interface contains many more definitions than just Init().

Comment: check your inheritance chain - this should (and does) work

Comment: Maybe because `Init` is not a public method

Comment: Just checked, and yes, I have the exact same setup, and it works for me. Maybe the `IBaseService` is declared in a assembly that is not referenced from the controller's assembly?

Comment: Actually, your code works for me fine

Comment: Thanks the quick response.  It was in effect a stupid error in the inheritance chain.  My dog is dying of heart failure under my desk, so not concentrating as usual.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the inheritance chain, I did a number of dumb things, too many and too dumb to detail here.
The valid point is that it works, what was wrong was the chain.

When I looked up on MSDN there was no simple example of this simple technique to back up my understanding, let alone any real documentation of this kind of use of inheritance with interfaces.

Comment: Sadly, I work at home, so my wife would call the men in white coats.  It's one thing shouting at a computer, quite another talking to a rubber duck.